# In Passage.render() using _.template(): SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm messing around with Snowman (Twine 2) and am trying to get a few if/else statements to do something based off what a person had done earlier (specifically, something based off how long a person presses "wait"). The first thing I tried had no issue:

```
<%
if(s.wait == 3){
    print('"Well, it appears that we did it correctly after all." His voice sounds deep and gutteral, with a hint of annoyance. "For being some prophesied being, you sure like to keep people waiting. Even my patience has limits."');
    s.ichor = 4;
    } else if(s.wait < 3){
    print('"So this is the prophesied being?" His voice is deep and gutteral, practically beastial. "While I cannot say I had any expectations, you just seem... a little plain."');
    s.ichor = 5;
    }
%>
```

The passage here runs without issue, but once it reaches the next one, it always give the following error:

In Passage.render() using _.template(): SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The next passage:

```
<%
if(s.wait == 3) {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "I'll admit, I was worried for a moment there, though that we had messed it up, that it was all for naught? Glad it wasn't!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
if(s.wait < 3 && s.wait > 0){
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitment, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 6;
    } else {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
%>
```

I am new to java script, so I don't know what the issue is. Any help would be well appreciated!

Comment: Your string ends on the apostrophe in `I'll`. Compare the helpful syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<%
if(s.wait == 3) {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "I'll admit, I was worried for a moment there, though that we had messed it up, that it was all for naught? Glad it wasn't!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
if(s.wait < 3 && s.wait > 0){
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitment, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 6;
    } else {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
%>
```

to

```
<%
if(s.wait == 3) {
    print("'How exciting that it worked!' His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. 'I'll admit, I was worried for a moment there, though that we had messed it up, that it was all for naught? Glad it wasn't!'");
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
if(s.wait < 3 && s.wait > 0){
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitment, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 6;
    } else {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
%>
```

Your quotes were causing the syntax error because you used singles on the outside.

You can also escape the quote as well:

```
<%
if(s.wait == 3) {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "I\'ll admit, I was worried for a moment there, though that we had messed it up, that it was all for naught? Glad it wasn't!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
if(s.wait < 3 && s.wait > 0){
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitment, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 6;
    } else {
    print('"How exciting that it worked!" His voice is filled with excitement, like a child looking a gift he just opened. "So this is what you look like- I look forward to working with you!"');
    s.sturm = 5;
    }
%>
```